# How to pin parse relation data in local data store?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Retrieved data and stored in local database but while trying to pull relation from the local database I get empty list which indicates that the relation data is not pinned to the local database.

```
public void retrieveThreadListStoreInDB()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Threads");
    query.include("postedBy");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null)
            {
                // Query is successful now lets load data from parse
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground((List<ParseObject>) list, new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if(e == null)
                        {
                            if(!isFinishing())
                            {
                                // TODO : Notify to refresh data
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.d("DEBUG","ERROR PINNING DATA WITH EXCEPTION : "+e);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
```

> So how should I pin "relation" data to the local database ???
>   What is the best way to read comments which is a relation. shall I store them in local datastore or pull data in the background ??

Comment: Hi, @Prabhu. Did you ever got relation pinning to work? I was able to do it by first pinning the relation objects and only then pinning the object that contains relation. Though this was working very inconsistently. Sometimes it would work, sometimes it would not. To me it seems that android implementation just doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you enableLocalDatastore store in application class `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());`

Parse local data store will not work with cache policy. We can access relational data like below

```
  private void getParseData() {
    if (parseObjectId != null) {
        mApp.show_PDialog(context, "Loading..");
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = new ParseQuery<>("Profile");
        parseQuery.getInBackground(parseObjectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    try {
                        newName = parseObject.getString("name");
                        newGender = parseObject.getString("gender");
                        newDOB.setTime(parseObject.getDate("dob"));
                        newTOB.setTime(parseObject.getDate("tob"));
                        newCurrentLocation = parseObject.getParseObject("currentLocation");
                        newPOB = parseObject.getParseObject("placeOfBirth");

                        if (newName != null) {
                            displayName.setText(newName);
                        }
                        if (newGender != null) {
                            gender.setText(newGender);
                        }
                        if (newDOB != null) {
                            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                            String subdateStr = df.format(newDOB.getTime());
                            datePicker.setText(subdateStr);
                        }
                        if (newTOB != null) {
                            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
                            df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                            String subdateStr = df.format(newTOB.getTime());
                            timepicker.setText(subdateStr);
                        }
                        if (newPOB != null) {
                            placeOfBirth.setText(newPOB.fetchIfNeeded().getString("name")
                                    + ", " + newPOB.fetchIfNeeded().getParseObject("Parent").fetchIfNeeded().getString("name") + ", " + newPOB.getParseObject("Parent").fetchIfNeeded().getParseObject("Parent").fetchIfNeeded().getString("name"));
                        }
                        if (newCurrentLocation != null) {
                            currentLocation.setText(newCurrentLocation.fetchIfNeeded().getString("name")
                                    + ", " + newCurrentLocation.fetchIfNeeded().getParseObject("Parent").fetchIfNeeded().getString("name") + ", " + newCurrentLocation.fetchIfNeeded().getParseObject("Parent").fetchIfNeeded().getParseObject("Parent").fetchIfNeeded().getString("name"));
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mApp.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } else {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: My local datastore is enabled I am trying to save Parse "RELATION" onto local datastore ? Is the above relevant ?

Comment: Please refer code there is method **fetchIfNeeded()** to get data from pointer objects first create and save relational objects  and then get its object id in your current table

Comment: can you explain a bit clearer what are you doing ?? or write comments in the code ? can we move this discussion to chat ?

Comment: [refer this](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#fetchIfNeeded())

Comment: I am using the local data store and want to store the relation in the local datastore. If I do what you want me to do I will end up making network calls while it is required fetching the data. Please do correct me If I am wrong and up vote if you have this similar question