# Retrieve data from parse based on object ID?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a list of objectId where I am trying to retrieve another list in another class where the pointer value equals the objectId of the current parseObject.

I realised that I am comparing a string "objectId" to a pointer "threadPointer" so can someone help me with the query to retrieve a list of items from a class if the objectId equals the threadPointer _Pointer value

```
public void retrieveThreadListStoreInDB()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Threads");
    query.include("postedBy");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Query is successful now lets load data from parse
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground((List<ParseObject>) list, new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (!isFinishing()) {
                                // TODO : Notify to refresh data
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("DEBUG", "ERROR PINNING DATA WITH EXCEPTION : " + e);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });

}

public void retrievePostsListStoreInDB()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
    query.include("postedBy");
    query.include("threadPointer");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Query is successful now lets load data from parse
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground((List<ParseObject>) list, new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (!isFinishing()) {
                                // TODO : Notify to refresh data
                                Log.d("DEBUG: ","Finished retrieval");
                                Log.d("DEBUG", list.toString());
                                ParseObject object = (ParseObject)list.get(1).get("threadPointer");
                                Log.d("DEBUG_THREAD_POINTER", object.getObjectId());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("DEBUG", "ERROR PINNING DATA WITH EXCEPTION : " + e);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });

}
```

This is where I am retrieving the ThreadList from local db

```
            public void retrieveThreadList(){
            List<ParseObject> parseObjectList = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Threads");
            query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
            query.fromLocalDatastore();

            // Data retrieval was successfull

            try {
               parseObjectList= query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (ParseObject parseObject : parseObjectList) {
                String title = (String) parseObject.get("threadTitle");
                ParseUser parseUser = (ParseUser) parseObject.get("postedBy");
                String profilePictureUrl="local";
                try {
                    profilePictureUrl = ((ParseFile) parseUser.get("profilePicture")).getUrl();
                }catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Log.d("DEBUG_FB","profilePicture not retrieved");
                }

                String threadObjectId = parseObject.getObjectId();
                Log.d("DEBUG_FB_THREAD_ID",threadObjectId);
                ParseQuery parseQueryToRetrievePosts = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
                parseQueryToRetrievePosts.fromLocalDatastore();

//----****** NEED HELP HERE ******----
parseQueryToRetrievePosts.whereEqualTo("threadPointer",parseObject.getObjectId());
                try {
                    List<ParseObject> postsList = parseQueryToRetrievePosts.find();
                    Log.d("DEBUG_FB_POSTS_LIST",postsList.toString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    /* To retrieve data over the network --- THIS WORKS WELL BUT I DONT WANT A NETWORK CALL
                ParseRelation <ParseObject> posts = parseObject.getRelation("postMessage");
                ParseQuery postsQuery = posts.getQuery();
                List<ParseObject> postsList = new ArrayList();
                try {
                    postsList=postsQuery.find();

                    for (ParseObject parseObject1: postsList)
                    {
                        String postMessage = (String)parseObject1.get("postMessage");
                        Log.d("DEBUG_FB_MSG", postMessage);
                    }
                    Log.d("DEBUG_FB_POSTS", postsList.toString());
                }catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
    */


                threadModelStore threadObject = new threadModelStore(title,profilePictureUrl);
                Log.d("DEBUG_FB", profilePictureUrl);
                Log.d("DEBUG_FB", title);
                threadItemList.add(threadObject);
            }
```

Sir my scenario is I have these classes

> 1. THREADS(Class) which has POSTS(RELATION TO _POSTS) class I want to retrieve the related posts of a particular thread. I was unable to pin
>      relations to local data store please let me know if there is a way to
>      do so ? -- (UNSOLVED)

2. So what I want to do is to compare the thread pointer in the POSTS
   class and retrieve the related posts. For this I needed to compare a
   string object id to pointer field _ThreadPointer in POSTS Class
   Suggest a possible solution -- SOLVED BY ( VED ).

Comment: it's possible this is your problem https://parse.com/questions/pfquery-wherekey-equalto-current-user

Comment: @JoeBlow I too have seen this but can you help me to use this with a sample code. (Please Note : I'm working on android )

Comment: you'd need to post clearly all your correct code, formatted, to get more help

Comment: @JoeBlow posted relevant code

Comment: you are passing threadObjectId  at this line  `parseQueryToRetrievePosts.whereEqualTo("threadPointer",threadObjectId);` , but instead of passing object id you should directly pass parseObject if it is pointer type.

Comment: @ved you are right (y). Is there any other way of storing the relational data on the local datastore

Comment: If I could do this it would be very useful as I need not search through the postsClass which increases it's efficiency so please comment and let me know... MANY THANKS...

Comment: I am just starting Local DataStore in my app, so I don't have enough knowledge  about it to tell you.Sorry dude :-(

Comment: @ved  If you can help please have a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715622/how-to-pin-parse-relation-data-in-local-data-store/32716870?noredirect=1#comment53276651_32716870

Comment: @ved cool thats ok once you are familiar please come back here !! If I figured out I will post :)

Comment: Ok. If I got any info related to this I will definitely post.

Answer (score 1):

```
ParseObject threadPointer=ParseObject.createWithoutData("Pointer_class_Name", "pointer_object_id");

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("className");
    query.whereEqualTo("_Pointer", threadPointer);
    query.include("_Pointer");
    query.findInBackground(new  FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> listCommunity, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "done");
            if(e==null){
              // access your data
            }else{
             // Error in retrieving data 
            }
```

Comment: create ParseObject from object id and then check pointer to this ParseObject.